# Laravel 10 not throwing any exception when using artisan test but phpunit works as expected

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I've updated a Laravel 8 project to Laravel 10. Everything works fine except my test.

I'm doing TDD, I have a test that doze a GET request to a route name that it's not defined, in this case when I run my test using the command `php artisan test --filter=test_get_home_page`, I expect to get a `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException` with the undefined route name but instead I get `get home page → This test did not perform any assertions`.

Basically it doesn't matter what the error is, I can even call a function/method that doesn't exist, the test out the same `get home page → This test did not perform any assertions` but if I use phpunit instead of `php artisan test` everything works as expected and I get the expected errors.

Please help, I've been hitting my head against the wall for 3 weeks with this problem.

Here is my test:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;

class SanityCheckTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_get_home_page()
    {
        $this->get(route('home'))->assertOk();
    } 
}
```

This is the output from `php artisan test --filter=SanityCheckTest`:

```bash
WARN  Tests\\Feature\\sanityCheckTest
! get home page → This test did not perform any assertions                                     0.77s

Tests:    1 risky (0 assertions)
Duration: 1.11s
```

And this is the output from `phpunit --filter=SanityCheckTest`:

```bash
PHPUnit 10.1.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.2.5
Configuration: /var/www/html/phpunit.xml

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:00.917, Memory: 18.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\\Feature\\sanityCheckTest::test_get_home_page
   Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\RouteNotFoundException: Route \[home\] not defined.

/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:467
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:810
/var/www/html/tests/Feature/sanityCheckTest.php:11
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:174

\--

There was 1 risky test:

1) Tests\\Feature\\sanityCheckTest::test_get_home_page
   This test did not perform any assertions

/var/www/html/tests/Feature/sanityCheckTest.php:9

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1, Risky: 1.
```

I've tried the same test in a new Laravel 10 project and it works as expected.

I've commented out all my custom code in `Tests/TestCase.php` / `Tests/CreateApplication.php` and no change.

I've checked the files: `/artisan`, `/App/Console/Kerner.php`, `/App/Http/kerner.php`, `/App/Exceptions/Handler.php` against the ones in the new laravel 10 project.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely using two different versions of phpunit.

`php artisan test` is going to use the phpunit version installed in your application's `vendor` directory. This is the version specified and installed by your application's `composer.json`/`composer.lock` files.

`phpunit` is going to run your globally installed version of `phpunit`, which is not related to your application's dependencies.

If you run `./vendor/bin/phpunit` instead of just `phpunit`, you should get the same error that `php artisan test` is showing.

To verify the versions being used, run the following commands:

```
phpunit --version
./vendor/bin/phpunit --version
```

---

If you want to update your globally installed version of phpunit, use the `global` keyword with your composer update command: `composer global update phpunit/phpunit`.

---

To ensure I'm always using the phpunit version installed for the application I'm working on, I use a phpunit alias instead of installing it globally. I use the following alias:

```
alias phpunit="./vendor/bin/phpunit"
```

Comment: I don't have phpunit installed globally i'm using laravel/sail and i have the phpunit aliased to the vendor  directory

Comment: I've fixed it. For anyone having this problem make sure that you are using the latest version of phpunit php artisan test --check-version or ./vendor/bin/phpunit --check-version and if your  not on the latest version update phpunit/phpunit to the latest version in your composer.json and run  composer update

Comment: @AndyBnOne That still doesn't explain your original question as to why `phpunit` and `php artisan test` were working differently. The only explanation I have is that `phpunit` was not calling `./vendor/bin/phpunit`, since that is what `php artisan test` calls under the hood.

Comment: @AndyBnOne and what versions did you have? Like 10.1.x is sort of latest, compared to 9.x, so what versions did you see when you ran those commands?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I think it was 10.0.3

Comment: @patricus I agree with you 100% as i understand  php artisan test it's just  a fancy  wrapper around phpunit. why i will get different results from phpunit and php artisan test and why a  minor version update will fix that  is beyond me all i know is that it's working now